# Tell progress of quicksort

Tags: progress-bar, quicksort

I am currently working on sorting files. At the moment I use heapsort for that because it is fairly easy to tell the progress of it. I mean there are two loops after one another and with some slight adjustments to how much weight you give one round of each of the two loops you have a very good estimate of the current progress and displaying a progress bar couldn't be easier.

Since quicksort is in most cases faster than heapsort I'd like to use that instead but I'm not sure how to tell the progress of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are three steps:

- Separate elements into two lists
- Sort left list
- Sort right list

You can give each step a part of the progress that it has to fill during execution. Let's say there are 100% in total. Step 1 gets 20%, step 2 40% and step 3 also 40% assuming that both lists have same size. This can be continued recursively.

The question is how big the fraction of each step actually is. The average time complexity of quicksort is `n*log(n)`. Let's say it takes `total = c*n*log(n)` comparisons to sort a list with `n` elements. Sorting a sublist with size `n*f` (`f < 1`) takes the following amount of comparisons.

```
c*(n*f)*log(n*f) = 
c*(n*f)*(log(n)+log(f)) =
(c*n*log(n))*f + c*n*log(f)*f =
total*f + c*n*log(f)*f
```

`c*n*log(f)*f` is negative because `f < 1`. The other sublist needs `total*(1-f) + c*n*log(1-f)*(1-f)` comparisons. So, the first step needs the following amount of comparisons.

```
total - (total*f + c*n*log(f)*f) - (total*(1-f) + c*n*log(1-f)*(1-f)) =
total - total*f - total*(1-f) - (c*n*log(f)*f) - (c*n*log(1-f)*(1-f)) =
- (c*n*log(f)*f) - (c*n*log(1-f)*(1-f)) =
- c*n*(log(f)*f+log(1-f)*(1-f))
```

The remaining question is: What is the value of `c`? If `c` is known and I did not make a mistake it should be possible to calculate the average time-fractions of the three steps using the formulas above.

Comment: That is an interesting aproach. But haven't you forgotten to calculate how much the first step is? Also if I only care for progress I should be able to leave c out.

Comment: The first step is calculated after the following sentence: "So, the first step needs the following amount of comparisons."

Comment: Right, when you divide one step by the sum of all steps c disappears. Nice. :)

Comment: I have spent some time thinking about this and I still can't figure out how I could tell the progress. Assuming I'm using a recursive implementation. How could I tell the progress inside the two loops that move the pointers from either side, having a signature like this ``quicksort(int* data, size_t upper, size_t lower, size_t total_size, double *progress)``. I'm honestly still scatching my head... (The ``progress`` pointer would be used inside the loop to set the progress for the progress-bar)

Comment: You can add startProgress and endProgress as parameters to your method. The method has to proceed until endProgress. You can implement the method as if each method call had it's own progress bar and convert the value: (localProgressPercent/100*(endProgress-startProgress))+startProgress. The progress of dividing the subsets can be calculated as j-i and also has to be converted from local to more global progress.

Comment: The conversion between the progress of each of the three steps and the progress of the whole method call needs the formulas in my answer.

Comment: I see. I will test that when I get to work on the project again

Comment: With this current calculations I would get 100% after the first "Step 1" completes... This can't be right. Either I'm really not understanding it correctly or it doesn't work. I guess providing some code would help. If you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry, I can't write C-code. Java is my main language. But I can give a calculation example. Parameters: startProgress: 0, endProgress: 100, n: 1000. I see a problem at this point. f is unknown before step 1 is finished. So, let's assume it's 0.5. Step 1 needs -c*1000*(-0.5-0.5)=c*1000 comparisons. Step 2 as well as step 3 needs c*1000*log(1000)*0.5+c*1000*(-0.5)=c*4983-c*500=c*4483 comparisons. So, step 1 has a fraction of 1000/(1000+4983+4983)=0.1, step 2 has 0.45 and step three 0.45 as well. The local progress of step 1 is (i+1+(n-j+1))/n. It's global progress is 0.1*(i+1+(n-j+1))/n.

Comment: Java is fine too. But as you mentioned. I would have to assume f. And that would yield somewhat inaccurate or invalid results.

Comment: The approach only estimates the progress anyway because the assumed complexity n*log(n) is only the average-complexity.